# How to post an image url to a group without showing image description?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to post an image url to a Facebook group I own.

This is how it's working as now:

[image]

I need to remove this part from the post:

[image]

This is my code:

```
print("Publishing:", message)
>> Publishing:  6 0 % OFF
             $19.99 WITH CODE 60JOQVPP
             https://amzn.to/3HLNrRY
             NURSAL 24 Modes Dual Channel TENS EMS Unit Muscle Stimulator for Pain Relief Therapy, Rechargeable TENS Machine Pulse Massager with 12 Pcs Electrode Pads/Continuous Stable Mode/Memory Function

print("Group:", group)
>> Group: 676543620253608

print("Link:", info[3])
>> Link: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71Q+-1LZ0zL._AC_SX679_.jpg

graph = GraphAPI(access_token=credentials['access_token'])
graph.put_object(group,'feed', message=message,link=info[3])
```

How can I post that image without the  m.media-amazon.com in the footer?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by posting it as an image:

POST {group_id}/photos

parameters:

url = link to image url

caption = image description

```
graph.put_object(group,'photos', caption=message,url=info[3])
```